# wait for shell script to finish before going to next line with Cron

Tags: cron, wait, tar, scp, gzip

--- file makebackup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump --all-databases | gzip -9 > /backup/temp_db.gz
tar -Pcf /backup/temp_ftp.tar /public_html/
tar -Pcf /backup/temp_backup.tar /home/temp_db.gz /backup/temp_ftp.tar
wait %%
/backup/upload.sh
```

--- file upload.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# connect via scp
spawn scp /backup/temp_backup.tar root@mybackup.com:/home/backup.tar
#######################
expect {
-re ".*es.*o.*" {
exp_send "yes\r"
exp_continue
}
-re ".*sword.*" {
exp_send "mypassword\r"
}
}
interact
```

When i look at `/backup` folder i see all files are there. In proper size 
When i look at destination site i see file that is 18 times less than what i have in source server in `/backup` folder.

When i just run it as `./makebackup.sh` it works properly when i run trough cron it does not. Is there way to execute `backup/upload.sh` **ONLY** once prior commands are finished?

```
15 12 * * 1,3,5 /backup/makebackup.sh 2>&1 >> /var/log/cron_makebackup.log
```

Cron log does not say anything at else than when i run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `wait %%` does, but this should help:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqldump --all-databases | gzip -9 > /backup/temp_db.gz
tar -Pcf /backup/temp_ftp.tar /public_html/
tar -Pcf /backup/temp_backup.tar /home/temp_db.gz /backup/temp_ftp.tar && \  
/backup/upload.sh || \
/backup/upload.sh
```

**NOTE**: never forget you can set up `scp` (and `ssh` too) [to work without passwords](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/)! I'd consider that instead of `expect` (which is a great tool).

This way `upload.sh` will be executed only after the last tar command finished either successful or with error exit code(s).

Some more info:

- If you write `test && command`, the `command` will only be executed if the test succeeds.
- If you write `test || command`, the `command` will only be executed if the test fails.

Run these tests:

```
$ true && echo "Yes."
Yes.
$ false || echo "Yes."
Yes.
```

Notice that the outcomes are entirely in keeping with one's intuition about such logical comparisons, and all is well as long as you don't think about the fact that true equals 0. :)
Here's another scheme commonly seen in shell script programming and interactive sessions:

```
$ command1 && command2 && command3 && command4
```

This line of code will not run the next command in the sequence unless the prior command has returned "true", meaning no errors. It is a way to avoid running a command if a required prior outcome is not present.

Also see [this article](http://steve-parker.org/sh/test.shtml) on `&&` and `||` testing.

HTH

Comment: wait %% supposedly waits for last triggered PID to finish. Can you tell me how this  && \, || \ technique called so i can find more info on it?

Comment: Is there particular reason why you use symbol "\" e.g. "&& \ /backup/upload.sh" Zsolt?

Comment: Is there particular reason why you use symbol "\" e.g. "&& \ /backup/upload.sh" Zsolt?

i if i have 4 commands how can i nest em e.g. "(((command1 && command2) && command3) && command4"

Comment: Okay it works with simple stuff like echo but it does NOT work for above scripts i used please verify yourself.

Comment: Sorry, but what you mean by not works? That's not an error riport. By the way: it should (must) work: if testing exit codes of previous commands fails in a *nix shell, then we have a problem :-) ...
And I had added some suggestion to the answer as well